# How can we disable a guard gem in Guardfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, guard

I have more than three guard gems in my Guardfile. When I run guard, I want a specific guard gem is to be disabled, without removing it from Guardfile. How should I disable it?

My next question is, rspec stops running test when it finds a first error. Is there any way to run all rspec errors at a time.

What are the guard gems are essential and easy to implement?

My Guardfile

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme
guard 'migrate' do
  watch(%r{^db/migrate/(\d+).+\.rb})
  watch('db/seeds.rb')
end

guard :annotate do
  watch( 'db/schema.rb' )

  # Uncomment the following line if you also want to run annotate anytime
  # a model file changes
  watch( 'app/models/*.rb' )

  # Uncomment the following line if you are running routes annotation
  # with the ":routes => true" option
  watch( 'config/routes.rb' )
end

guard :bundler do
  watch('Gemfile')
  # Uncomment next line if your Gemfile contains the `gemspec' command.
  # watch(/^.+\.gemspec/)
end

guard :rspec do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml|\.slim)$})          { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml|slim)$})     { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end

guard :rubocop do
  watch(%r{.+\.rb$})
  watch(%r{(?:.+/)?\.rubocop\.yml$}) { |m| File.dirname(m[0]) }
end

### Guard::Sidekiq
#  available options:
#  - :verbose
#  - :queue (defaults to "default") can be an array
#  - :concurrency (defaults to 1)
#  - :timeout
#  - :environment (corresponds to RAILS_ENV for the Sidekiq worker)
guard 'sidekiq', :environment => 'development' do
  watch(%r{^workers/(.+)\.rb$})
end

guard 'rails' do
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch(%r{^(config|lib)/.*})
end


# Sample guardfile block for Guard::Haml
# You can use some options to change guard-haml configuration
# output: 'public'                   set output directory for compiled files
# input: 'src'                       set input directory with haml files
# run_at_start: true                 compile files when guard starts
# notifications: true                send notifictions to Growl/libnotify/Notifu
# haml_options: { ugly: true }    pass options to the Haml engine

guard 'puma' do
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch(%r{^config|lib|api/.*})
end

guard 'rake', :task => 'build' do
  watch(%r{^my_file.rb})
end
```

Comment: what do you mean the guardfile? show it

Comment: to rerun `rspec` in `guard` hit the enter button, however you should not be having more than one `guard` in a `Gemfile`

Answer (score 0):

Group your Guard plugins into [groups](https://github.com/guard/guard#group). This allows you to [select a specific group from the command line](https://github.com/guard/guard#-g--group-option) or switch them at runtime using the [scope](https://github.com/guard/guard#scope) interactor command.